# Get content of module file from Ruby custom type in Puppet

Tags: ruby, file-io, puppet

I am currently writing a Ruby custom type for Puppet and I must load the content of a file which is located in the same module in the 'files' folder. Is there a function accessible from the provider that can give me the content of the file addressed by `"puppet:///modules/my_module/test.yaml"`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get it working... Is this a proper solution?

```
file = Puppet::Parser::Files.find_file("my_module/my_file",
                Puppet::Module.find('my_module').environment)
File.open('/tmp/test', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read(file)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is.

The manifest of your module should take care of copying the file to the agent through a `file` resource, so that the provider can use it from a known location.

Comment: That sounds good. I think then it would be best to wrap the custom type by a defined type that does the copying job.

Comment: Have a look to my post... What do you think, is this working?

Comment: @Herr-Herner as csanchez points out, this will generally not work because the type code runs agent side, not master side.

Answer (score 0):

Functions run on the server, types in the agent. If you create a function that returns the content of the file at the server, using standard Ruby code, you could use that function to inject the value in your type.

There are some [caveats](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html) about what you can do with functions though.